# Too many tags to choose from on CV

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

When creating my CV, I had to choose between

- C#
- C#-1.0,
- C#-2
- .NET
- etc

A person searching for CV will have to do the same.  This will lead to a lot of CVs not being matched.

Options.

1. Reduce the number of tags, so that
   there is only one C# tag etc
2. Form
   the tags into a tree**S** (or graphs), so that when
   .NET is searched for all sub tags are found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- C# and .NET aren't the same.
- Which one would you choose? Would you really take C#-1.0 or C#-2.0 instead of the more general C#?

I think 99% of all people will choose C# in this example. The same should be true for other tags.

If one would like to do something about it: sort tags by occurrence or show it in brackets like this: C# (40000)

Comment: if you are looking for a .net programmer, a C# programmer is lickly to be able to do the job!